# Angular 5 ng-content issue

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular5, ng-content

I have weird issue when I implement **ng-content** between two component in Angular 5.

This my first component is FooterComponent

```
<div class="footer">
  <ng-content select="footer"></ng-content>
</div>
```

And footer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And this the second component is AboutComponent

```
<app-footer>
  <footer>
   this is my footer
  </footer>
</app-footer>
```

Also this app-module.ts in first try and in second try I import about.module.ts or footer.module.ts instead of AboutComponent and FooterComponent.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And app.component.html have just router-outlet tag

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So I have two issues first one is when I run Angular using **ng serve** command line I have not see any output. The second and important one is when I run **ng test** command line I see this Bug...

```
AboutComponent should create
  Failed: Template parse errors:
  'app-footer' is not a known element:
  1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
     this module.
  2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
     the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
     [ERROR ->]<app-footer>
     <footer>
     this is my footer
     "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AboutComponent.html@0:0
```

So I have been try many solution like

1. Generate about.module.ts and import **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** and try **NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA**. And also import FooterComponent and finally import about.module.ts in app.module.ts
2. I do the same thing with FooterComponent.
3. I have been try using **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** and **NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA** in every module and it's a give me the same result.

And this package.json

```
{
 "name": "ng-app",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build --prod",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Finally this new Angular-cli Project I created.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the typescript code for FooterComponent?

Comment: I post footer.component.ts and nothing special just I use selector in AboutComponent.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed, I must admit ... Cannot see what is wrong. Could you post your code in github or any other site? Without locally trying it, I don't see a way to help you

Comment: I deploy this on my github https://github.com/himasamo/Angular-Assue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is include the `RouterModule` in the *app.module.ts*. You are trying to use the router outlet (`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`) without that. That will not work.

Updated *app.module.ts*:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FooterModule } from './footer/footer.module';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FooterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: '', component: FooterComponent}
    ])
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See the new import for the `RouterModule`. Also, after adding `RouterModule` to the imports array, I also added a default route that goes to the `FooterComponent`. I needed something to route to, that is what I chose. Change this to what ever you like as your application progresses.

**Mind you**, even with these changes, you will see nothing in the browser. You will need to add some content to the footer in order to see something. I will leave that part up to you. If you right-click and Inspect the main page while running `ng serve`, you will see that the footer elements do get rendered (they just don't have any valuable content, yet).

As far as testing, you need to add the `FooterComponent` to the declarations section in the spec for the `AboutComponent`, along with the import. Updated spec below.

```
import { FooterComponent } from './../footer/footer.component';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

describe('AboutComponent', () => {
let component: AboutComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AboutComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ AboutComponent, FooterComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

Since the `AboutComponent` is hosting the `FooterComponent`, the unit test needs to know about all the components in the mix. This takes care of that.

Then, in order to clear the eventual error you will get related to testing the `AppComponent`, you need to mock a router outlet for use in the spec. That code is below.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, RouterOutletStubComponent
    ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));
it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
}));
it(`should have as title 'app'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app');
}));
});


@Component({selector: 'router-outlet', template: ''})
class RouterOutletStubComponent { }
```

Since you removed all the original HTML for the `AppComponent` to use it as a router outlet, I had to remove one of the unit tests, since it was no longer needed.

The `RouterOutletStubComponent` is the interesting thing here. This allows the `AppComponent` unit tests to run successfully. All the `AppComponent` is at this point is a router outlet container.

Happy coding!